# "how comes down" vs. "It all comes down"

Tags: pronunciation

[Meaning of come down on Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/come-down)

> to fall and land on the ground

[A tutorial sounds like](https://youtu.be/Y3JOteXB9do?list=PLZn8I1YOpwVsVk1qE4IzcmCix-eFn1YV4&t=345)

> This is why Hebrew may come across as aggressive, but it's basically the way we
>   stress words. **How comes down** to the language, people.

whereas the official TRANSCRIPT gives

> **It all comes down** to the language, people.

Which one is correct? What does that mean? The meaning on Cambridge Dictionary doesn't seem to apply here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transcript is correct, and ‘come(s) down to’ is actually the expression used in this case. It means ‘is dependent on’. So in the example, it’d be:

> It is all dependent on the language, people.

If I’m interpreting it correctly, this means that the sound of Hebrew when it’s spoken shouldn’t determine what tone you think someone has. Rather, you should interpret sentences in Hebrew based on the words in the sentence, not what the tone of the speaker sounds like to someone who doesn’t have Hebrew as a mother tongue.